# Automatically swapping an image for another on the server.

Tags: ios

Just a quick question.
I am trying to figure out a way to automatically swap a file for another one on the same location on the server at a given time.
This image is the splash screen of my IOS app and the url is pointing to it.

Let's say I have a new version of "picture1.jpg" that needs to take the place of the old "picture1.jpg" on Sunday at 12pm (name need to remain the same).

This picture will need to change up to 20 times a month and I want to automate the whole process.

Is that possible? How can this be achieved? I read about Cron Job, anything a bit easier?
The image is hosted on GoDaddy.com.

Thanks for the pointers.

Farcat

Answer (score 0):

You can make a php script that shows a different image depending on the current time.

Let's say you store two images: `images/splash.jpg` and `images/special-splash.jpg`. You can do something like:

`images/picture1.php`

```
<?php
    if(timeToShowSpecial()) {
        header('Location: images/special-splash.jpg');
    } else {
        header('Location: images/splash.jpg');
    }
?>
```

`timeToShowSpecial()` could be as complex as you want, then.